# Separar texto de un array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un `array` con `id` y `description` donde se tiene 2 **roles**, **Propietario** y **Arrendatario**, estaba intentando separar el rol de cada `description` y agregarlo a un `array` nuevo con su `id` correspondiente, algo como:

```
{
  id: 1,
  description: "Propietario"
},
{
  id: 2,
  description: "Arrendatario"
}
```

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
var rent = "Arrendatario";
var owner = "Propietario";
var obj = [{
    id: 1,
    description: "1664 - Propietario"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "1637 - Arrendatario - Finalizado"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "1735 - Arrendatario"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    description: "LA6780 - Arrendatario"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    description: "1638 - Arrendatario - Finalizado"
  }
];
console.log(obj);
```

El problema es que necesito separar la palabra Arrendatario o Propietario del String algo con split()

Comment: Hola. No entiendo cuál es el problema. ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: @César El problema es que necesito separar la palabra Arrendatario o Propietario del String  algo con split()

Comment: No creo que necesites separarlos, simplemente necesitas asgurarte de que la palabra esté en la descripción. Creo que con eso bastaría, ¿no?

Comment: @César Necesito esa palabra para luego colocarla en un input como valor

Comment: Creo que debes plantear mejor tu problema y lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: quieres filtrar el arreglo dependiendo el tipo `const arrendatario = obj.filter(item => item.description.indexOf(rent) > -1);
            const prop = obj.filter(item => item.description.indexOf(owner) > -1);`

Comment: @JackNavaRow eso es a lo que iba. Basta con saber si la palabra está contenida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para realizar la tarea sólo debes recorrer el `array` e ir agregando elementos al nuevo `array` de acuerdo a si el valor del atributo `description` contiene `Arrendatario` o `Propietario`.

```js
const rent = "Arrendatario";
const owner = "Propietario";
const obj = [{
    id: 1,
    description: "1664 - Propietario"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "1637 - Arrendatario - Finalizado"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "1735 - Arrendatario"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    description: "LA6780 - Arrendatario"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    description: "1638 - Arrendatario - Finalizado"
  }
];
let newArray = [];
obj.forEach((document) => {
  let desc = '';
  let id = document.id;
  if (document.description.indexOf(rent) > -1) {
    desc = rent;
  }
  if (document.description.indexOf(owner) > -1) {
    desc = owner;
  }
  newArray.push({
    id: id,
    description: desc
  });
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Como puedes ver el código es bastante explicativo. Se verifica el valor de cada atributo y se almacena en el nuevo `array` lo que deseas.

Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes resolverlo con un map y un includes:

```js
const rent = "Arrendatario";
const owner = "Propietario";
const obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    description: "1664 - Propietario"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: "1637 - Arrendatario - Finalizado"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: "1735 - Arrendatario"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    description: "LA6780 - Arrendatario"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    description: "1638 - Arrendatario - Finalizado"
  }
];


const nuevoArray = obj.map(item => 
  item.description.includes(rent) ? 
   {...item,  description: rent} :
   {...item,  description: owner}
);

console.log(nuevoArray);
```